# To group number of data upto a certain limit

Tags: python

If anyone could help me out to solve this problem, that would be greatly appreciated. Here I have a list of weights (kg) of a few samples.

```
weight_list = [0.2, 0.4, 1.0, 0.7, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]
```

The maximum weight that could be for any sample is 1 kg. I need to sum sample weights until the total mass is not exceeding 1 kg. For instance, this is what I expect after summing the weights of samples based on the given condition.

```
grouped_list = [0.6, 1.0, 0.8, 0.4, 1.0, 0.9]
```

this is what I have so far, but it loops over infinitely.

```
weight_list = [0.2, 0.4, 1.0, 0.7, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]
grouped_list = []
for weight in weight_list:
    total = 0
    while total <= 1:
        total += weight
        if total > 1:
            total -= weight
            grouped_list.append(total)
            total = 0
        else:
            grouped_list.append(total)
```

***I am open*** to entirely new methods as well, if there any module or easy way to group this, please kindly assist me.

Comment: **need to sum sample weights until the total mass is not exceeding 1 kg.**. If each of the elements on the list is in `KG` then how is the `sum([0.6, 1.0, 0.8, 0.4, 1.0, 0.9])` (or the total "mass") below 1kg. It is `4.7` KGs. How is this your desired output? Your code is doing something entirely different that what you are saying in text

Comment: Let me to clear, weight of the first sample is 0.2 kg, and the second is 0.4 kg. If we add sample one and two, the total mass is 0.6 kg which is less than 1.0 kg, but if we add the third sample as well, then the  total mass exceeds 1.0 kg and gives 1.6 kg. In fact 1.0 kg (third sample) has to be left as it is. Then proceeds so on further.

Comment: we should use stack for this kind of use. It would make the program simple to understand. Let me know if you would like to know  the stack version

Comment: Hello Ubaid, indeed I am certainly interested to know. Please share your knowledge with me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, you are currently looping for the same weight everytime, instead, you should iterate the list like this:

```
weight_list = [0.2, 0.4, 1.0, 0.7, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]
grouped_list = []
total, count = 0, 0
# increment counter over the weight list
while count < len(weight_list):
    total += weight_list[count]
    if total > 1:
        # add the weight if it recently exceeded 1 by subtracting recent weight
        total -= weight_list[count]
        # round to 1 decimal point (due to floating point math)
        grouped_list.append(round(total, 1))
        total = 0
    else:
        count += 1
# add the left-over total if < 1
if total < 1:
    grouped_list.append(round(total, 1))
print(grouped_list)
```

gives

```
[0.6, 1.0, 0.8, 0.4, 1.0, 0.9]
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party I guess but it was fun working on the problem so here is my solution using a for loop instead of while :

```
weight_list = [0.2, 0.4, 1.0, 0.7, 0.1, 0.4, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.2, 0.1]
grouped_list = []

total = 0.0

def main():
    group(len(weight_list), weight_list)
    print(grouped_list)

def group(n, l):
    global total
    for i in range(n):
        total += l[i]
        if total > 1:
            total -= weight_list[i]
            grouped_list.append(round(total, 1))
            total = l[i]
            continue
        if total == 1:
            grouped_list.append(round(total, 1))
            continue
        
main()
```